# ModelAttribute fields are null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, null, modelattribute

I am facing this strange behaviour whith Spring MVC and JSP where the `ModelAttribute` is sent to the JSP with populated fields but when it is returned to the controller all the fields are `null`.

So first of all I put an object as attribute in the model.

```
@PostMapping("qcm")
public String qcm(@ModelAttribute("qcm") Qcm formQcm, Model model) {

    Qcm q = props.getQcm(formQcm.getDomaine(), formQcm.getMode());

    model.addAttribute("qcm", q);

    this.qcm = q;

    return "qcm";
}
```

The ModelAttribute here works just fine. But note that I add a new attribute to the model here.

In the `qcm.jsp` page I display a form with some information from the `qcm` object I put in the model earlier. That means there is no way I send the fields of `qcm` as `null`  in the first place.

Here is `qcm.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">QCM</h1>
        <form:form action="sendqcm" modelAttribute="qcm" method="POST">

            <c:forEach var="question" items="${qcm.questions}">
                <p>${question.data}?</p>
                <c:forEach var="reponse" items="${question.reponses}">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <form:radiobutton path="${question.chosenReponse}" value="${reponse}" label="${reponse.data}" class="form-check-input"/>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
            <input type="submit" value="envoyer" class="save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The informations are displayed just fine. I mapped the `action` to the `sendqcm` controller. Here it is:

```
@PostMapping("sendqcm")
public String sendqcm(@ModelAttribute("qcm") Qcm formQcm, Model model) {

System.out.println("Domaine -> " + formQcm.getDomaine());
System.out.println("Mode -> " + formQcm.getMode());

for(Question q : formQcm.getQuestions()) {
    System.out.println(q.getChosenReponse());
}

for (Question q : formQcm.getQuestions()) {
    if (q.answeredCorrectly())
        score++;
}

model.addAttribute("score", score);

return "reponses";
}
```

The two lines of `System.out.println()` return null and then the program fails with `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fr.insa.controller.AppController.sendqcm(AppController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the @ControllerAdvice assists a controller and in particular, so @ModelAttribute methods that apply to all @RequestMapping methods.